# Unable to query with SSRS parameter to iHistorian

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, oledb, historian

I'm trying to get iHistorian to accept a query from SSRS using a parameter for Date, with OLEDB.

Query is like this in the Report Builder Dataset

```
SELECT timestamp, tagname, value
FROM     ihrawdata
WHERE timestamp LIKE '@date'
```

This gives error message from Report Builder when running report preview:

> iHOLEDB.iHistorian.1' failed with no error message available, result code: E_INVALIDARG(0x80070057)

Anyone know how I can get a parameter from SSRS query to work with iHistorian?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to query Proficy Historian via the OLEDB with parameters is to create a stored procedure and have the report use the stored procedure as its source, passing the parameters you need.

Here's an example using your example of a timestamp param to filter Historian data.
You could also extend the stored proc pretty easily to pass in parameters for SamplingMode, DateFrom, DateTo, etc

**Step 1** Use the the [help documentation](http://help.geautomation.com/Historian55/Subsystems/iHistODB/content/odb_configuring_the_ihistorian_ole_db_provider_as_a_linked_server.htm) to install the OLEDB driver onto your SQL Server instance and create the linked server pointing to your Historian.

**Step 2** Verify the OLEDB driver and Linked Server exist. They should look something like this:

[image: OLEDB Linked Server config]

**Step 3** Create a stored procedure in the DB that uses the new linked server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Historian_GetDataByTimestamp]
    @HistorianLinkedServer NVARCHAR(100),
    @Timestamp DATETIME

AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @Result TABLE
       (TagName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        [Timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL,
        [Value] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        Quality NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT tagname, timestamp, value, quality
                FROM OPENQUERY ("' + @HistorianLinkedServer + '",
               ''SET SamplingMode = RawByTime
                 SELECT tagname, timestamp, value, quality
                 FROM ihRawData
                 WHERE Timestamp = "' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @Timestamp, 20) + '"'')';

      INSERT INTO @Result EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

      SELECT Tagname, [Timestamp], [Value], Quality
      FROM @Result
      ORDER BY TagName DESC, [Timestamp]
END;
```

**Step 4** Test your stored proc from SSMS or similar:

[image: Test Stored Proc]

**Step 5** Configure your SSRS dataset to query via the stored proc, passing parameters as necessary. Here's a [step by step guide](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ssrs-report-for-stored-procedure-with-parameters) to configure that if you've not done that before, it's super simple...